# Unity3D control Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

how to change the shader`s custom value by code?
e.g.

```
transform.collider.material.MyShader.CustomValue = 2
```

(I know its wrong,just like this)
shader code:

```
Properties {
    _Value  ("CustomValue", range (0,128)) = 10
}
```

I want to use C# to cotntrol the "CusomValue",How to code?
Use

```
renderer.material.SetFloat("_Value", newValue);
```

can do it!thx!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Material methods](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Material.html).  For example:

```
 renderer.material.SetFloat("_Value", newValue);
```

Comment: Successful~  Thanks! =3=